# How to add exceptions to apache reverse proxy rules

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to set a Apache reverse proxy so that requests get proxyed to another application running on 8080. However, I want some directories to be directly served rather than forwarded to proxy. What I want is:

http://localhost/ -> http:// localhost:8080/myapp

**http:// localhost/images -> /var/www/html/images**

http:// localhost/anything-else -> http:// localhost:8080/myapp/anyhthing-else

My current httpd.conf is

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyTimeout 600
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http:// localhost:8080/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http:// localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/myapp/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

What configuration should I do to make the local path exception to work?

Thank you, Tania

Comment: this is not a duplicate of the question on mod_rewrite. its about mod_proxy..

Answer (score 30):

I found the solution.

To make an exclusion for /myapp, I need to add

```
ProxyPass /myapp !
```

as the first ProxyPass directive as exclusions should come before the general rule.

I also need to add

```
RewriteCond !^/myapp/(.*)
```

before RewriteRule to exclude it from RewriteRule