# Proxying only subdomains of localhost

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, subdomain, localhost

I'm trying to figure out how to proxy requests to subdomains of localhost to another port on Apache, but not proxy requests only to localhost (with no subdomains). I can't get it to work. Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
  ServerName subdomain2.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
  NoProxy "localhost"
</VirtualHost>
```

The proxying of subdomain1 and subdomain2 to localhost:3000 works, but localhost is also proxied to localhost:3000. How do I prevent that?

EDIT

With the help of @Esa and @HBruijn but I still can't get it to work. I've edited virtual hosts the http.conf to the following. The aliases work but now the subdomains don't work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    Alias /alias1 "/alias1"
    Alias /alias2 "/alias2"
    Alias /alias3 "/alias3"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain2.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add exceptions to apache reverse proxy rules](http://serverfault.com/questions/80123/how-to-add-exceptions-to-apache-reverse-proxy-rules)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to simply create separate VirtualHost entries, each with the correct settings for that (sub) domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.localhost
#   Possibly a single VirtualHost for all subdomains with a catch-all ServerAlias:
#   ServerAlias *.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain2.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Same answer at the same time. However, I consider both as helpful since your answer gives directly the correct configuration and mine is more describing and educational.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the [`ServerName` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) works. See:

> The `ServerName` directive may appear anywhere within the definition of
>   a server. However, each appearance overrides the previous appearance
>   (within that server).
>
> If no `ServerName` is specified, the server attempts to deduce the
>   client visible hostname by first asking the operating system for the
>   system hostname, and if that fails, performing a reverse lookup on an
>   IP address present on the system.
>
> If no port is specified in the `ServerName`, then the server will use
>   the port from the incoming request. For optimal reliability and
>   predictability, you should specify an explicit hostname and port using
>   the ServerName directive.

You can't have two `ServerName` directives in the same [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost), so at first you need to separate:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain2.localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in order to have the `localhost:80` to do something else than falling back to the default configuration (the first `VirtualHost` within the same port, currently `subdomain1.localhost`) you need to have own `<VirtualHost>` [Section Container](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) for it. So you could add this **above** the previous:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, your [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)es having identical `[URL-path]` and `file-path|directory-path` didn't make any sense, but I suppose there was some real filesystem locations on the right side.

Comment: Thanks! However, I still can't get it to work. I've edited the question to show how I changed configuration (which doesn't work).